# ansible ec2 with_items failling

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

here we have an ec2 module in a playbook:

```
---
# This playbook creates dev-test instances at AWS.

- name: test creation
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: False
  tasks:
  - name: instance creation
    ec2:
      key_name: dev-key
      group_id: sg-55667788
      instance_type: t2.micro
      image: ami-cd0f5cb6
      wait: yes
      wait_timeout: 300
      volumes:
        - device_name: /dev/sda1
          volume_type: gp2
          volume_size: 32
          delete_on_termination: True        
        - device_name: /dev/xvdb
          volume_type: gp2
          volume_size: 1
          delete_on_termination: True
        - device_name: /dev/xvdc
          volume_type: gp2
          volume_size: 200
          delete_on_termination: True
      vpc_subnet_id: "{{ item.vpc_subnet_id }}"
      zone: "{{ item.zone }}"
      region: us-east-1
      assign_public_ip: no
      private_ip: "{{ item.private_ip }}"
      instance_tags:
        Name: "{{ item.tag_name }}"
      user_data: |
                 #!/bin/bash
                 mkswap /dev/xvdb
                 swapon /dev/xvdb
                 echo "/dev/xvdb none swap sw 0 0" >> /etc/fstab
                 echo "n
                 e
                 1


                 n
                 l


                 w
                 " | fdisk /dev/xvdc
      with_items: 
        - { vpc_subnet_id: 'subnet-11223344', zone: 'us-east-1d', private_ip: '172.31.5.15', tag_name: 'dev-test.vpc-01' }
        - { vpc_subnet_id: 'subnet-44332211', zone: 'us-east-1e', private_ip: '172.31.7.13', tag_name: 'dev-test.vpc-01' }
```

And here the error output:

```
test@test:~$ ansible-playbook --check create-ec2.yml 
 [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: all

 [WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available


PLAY [instance creation] *********************************************************************************************************

TASK [instance creation] ************************************************************************************************************
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'item' is undefined\n\nThe error appears to have been in 'create-ec2.yml': line 8, column 5, but may\nbe elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax problem.\n\nThe offending line appears to be:\n\n  tasks:\n  - name: cria instancia\n    ^ here\n\nexception type: <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleUndefinedVariable'>\nexception: 'item' is undefined"}
    to retry, use: --limit @create-ec2.retry

PLAY RECAP ***********************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=0    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

I don't see where the mistake is. Where is this item undefined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`with_items` is wrongly indented. It should be on a task level, not on task parameters level.

In result the directive for `with`-loop is ignored and the variable `item` is not defined.